# i am facing this error in Node.js 'INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN' how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-development-server

I was learning to make a basic server in Node.js but I face this error every time I try to run my server
I have provided an image of my code and an image of the error as well please help if you can

**Code**
[image: This is code image]

**Error**
[image: This is error image]

Comment: Header name must be a valid one. `"Content-Type"` instead of `"content type"`

Comment: Please post code as text and not as image ...

Answer (score 0):

The proper line of code should be:

```
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-type": "text/html" });
```

According to the error shown, it looks like you just
wrote

> "content type"

**instead of**

> "Content-type"

Comment: thanks man it solved the problem